# How to invoke system camera from custom Windows phone 8.1.app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, camera, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to use default camera app(Nokia/Microsoft camera) in my  app?
I would like to, on btn click to call system camera. Take a picture with it, and then upload that picture to the server from my app.

If there is no way to do that, what is the best way to create camera app so user can use zoom, flashlight, etc.

EDIT:
This was available in older versions of Windows phone, and it was simple to use
like this:

```
 CameraCaptureTask camera = new CameraCaptureTask();
        camera.Show();
        camera.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(camera_Completed);
```

I don't understand why would MS remove this ability from Windows phone 8.1

Thank you,
regards

Comment: The camera capture task was based on Silverlight APIs and was valid for Windows phone 7 and 8 that used silverlight Pages . The camera APIs are now based on WinRT Universal APIs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera capture task was based on Silverlight APIs and was valid for Windows phone 7 and 8 that used silverlight Pages . The camera APIs are now based on WinRT Universal APIs . Have a look at this

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/17

Comment: So basically if i want to do this in Windows Phone RT, I need to create those buttons for camera settings myself, or use FileOpenPicker to get to system camera, but then user needs to press camera btn from Pictures Library.
I think i'll go with Silverlight app instead, and use CameraCaptureTask.

Thank you

Comment: Just check whether after VS 2013 CTP4 update you have the option to create Silverlight pages or not . I dont think we have one !! Launchers have gone in WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this link,
[capturing an image in windows store 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn376408.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but only in Windows  8.1 apps, not in Windows phone 8.1

As it says on the link:
"Note  The CameraCaptureUI control is not available on Windows Phone 8.1 devices. "